# How to split two dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have string like below:

```
"test[2][1]"
"test[2][2]"
etc
```

Now, I want to split this string to like this:

```
split[0] = "test"
split[1] = 2
split[2] = 1

split[0] = "test"
split[1] = 2
split[2] = 2
```

I tried split in javascript but no success.How can it be possible?

CODE:

```
string.split('][');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. `.replace(/]/g, '')` gets rid of the right square bracket.
2. `.split('[')` splits the remaining `"test[2[1"` into its components.

```js
var str1 = "test[2][1]";
var str2 = "test[2][2]";

var split = str1.replace(/]/g, '').split('[');
var split2 = str2.replace(/]/g, '').split('[');

alert(split);
alert(split2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :
`string.split(/\]?\[|\]\[?/)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function splitter (string) {
   var arr = string.split('['),
       result = [];

   arr.forEach(function (item) {
       item = item.replace(/]$/, '');
       result.push(item);
   })

   return result;
}

console.log(splitter("test[2][1]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as this format is used you can do

```
var text = "test[1][2]";
var split = text.match(/\w+/g);
```

But you will run into problems if the three parts contain something else than letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can split with the `[` character and then remove last character from all the elements except the first.

```
var str = "test[2][2]";

var res = str.split("[");
for(var i=1, len=res.length; i < len; i++)  res[i]=res[i].slice(0,-1); 

alert(res);
```